# "rfkill list all" shows nothing in command line

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bluetooth, ralink, rfkill

I'm using dual boot of Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 8.1. When I run rfkill list all it shows as follows:

```
:~$ rfkill list all
:~$
```

Please Help.

**update:**

Laptop model: Fujisu Lifebook LH532. It has a WiFi and a Bluetooth device(ralink rt3290). Both of them work fine in windows. In Ubuntu, I made my WiFi working by web help and tried for Bluetooth but still no luck.

*lspci*  is:

```
:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
03:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
```

and *iwconfig* is

```
:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

ra0       Ralink STA  ESSID:""  Nickname:"RT3290STA"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:1 Mb/s   
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Link Quality=10/100  Signal level:0 dBm  Noise level:0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Do you have a wireless (WiFI/Bluetooth) card? What is the output of `lspci` and `iwconfig`? Please edit the question to include the output.

Comment: You are right. I'm on it.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't meant to show anything if there is nothing to show. This command doesn't give a message like `no wireless devices`, which would be an improvement.

From the man page:

```
list [type]
             List the current state of all available rfkill-using devices, or
              just all of the given type.
```

So if there is nothing to list, then it won't show anything.

My output of `rfkill list` is the same as yours - nothing.

Comment: Yes, i got your point and understand that this is not the main problem. Thats why I've updated my question.